# Why are my questions no longer being accepted?

Tags: discussion

Why are my questions no longer being accepted? - That means **I am banned from putting questions !!!**:

> **You can’t post new questions right now**
>
> **Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from your account** because most of your questions need improvement or are out of scope for this site. See the Help Center page Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account? to learn more.
>
> Please do not create a new account. Instead, work on improving your existing questions by editing them to comply with the site's guidelines and address any feedback you've received. You can also continue to contribute to the site in other ways, such as editing other posts to improve them.

**That's what shows up when I use the "Ask Question" button on ELL.**

What's wrong with my questions all of a sudden? My last question was [Meaning of "They must have adjusted to London, more or less"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/345294/meaning-of-they-must-have-adjusted-to-london-more-or-less?noredirect=1#comment668301_345294). Is this a wrong question? All the time there weren't any disturbances and the process was calm and affable. I don't understand that?

Comment: Getting negative reactions sucks. We've all been there and I'd like to help you figure out if it's something you're doing, or just unwarranted reactions from other users. Please [edit] your question to tell us specifically which reactions you don't understand. For instance, is it the close votes? If so, please tell us why you don't think the reason for the close votes applies to your question. If there are other recent questions of yours that have gotten a bad reception, please also link them and tell us which reactions you don't understand. We're here for you :)

Comment: What do you understand by "Getting negative reactions sucks"?

Comment: If you really want to know, gotube is basically saying that nobody likes receiving negative feedback. The only people who can explain why your questions are attracting downvotes are the same users who have cast their downvotes. You're one of few who actually name and link back to the source. Yet, for some that is not enough. I think the real problem lies with the general decline of interesting questions, if the site had ten good questions a day users would be more engaged.

Comment: #2 And if hi-rep users were more engaged they would probably be more generous with upvotes, too. On the positive side, well maybe not exactly "positive", three of the five downvoters have either visited, posted, commented, or voted on meta in the last two years. And two users have openly expressed interest in running for moderator, if an election were held on ELL in 2024. So, they could probably explain why they downvoted (if they did, we don't know) or give a more detailed explanation for closing the post.

Comment: I should have said "..three of the five users who voted **to close**".

Comment: The use of "must" can be looked up in any dictionary. So, the question is asking for basic meaning. Oxford Dictionary via Google: 2.
*expressing an opinion about something that is logically very likely*.

Comment: @ gotube - I feel compelled to repeat my question: What do you understand by "Getting negative reactions sucks"? Please say it in concrete terms. Whose reactions  suck? What reactions suck? Tell me examples of reactions that suck.

Comment: There is a lot of advice for asking questions that will be well-received in [Please, everyone ... details. Please!](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/9161) including [a post that lists some examples of well-written questions](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4584/9161). Don't let people discourage you from reading certain books because the language is outdated - you can always ask questions in [chat] if you don't want to write up a detailed questions or you feel like people might be getting tired of that source.

Comment: @philphil I didn't say that reactions suck. I said that (you) ***getting*** negative reactions (from other users) sucks. I hope that clears up my comment enough for you to improve this question.

Comment: @ gotube - **No, there aren't any negative reactions from other users that suck and that's why there isn't anything that sucks, actually!!!** And that's why I'm wondering **why I am banned from putting questions all of a sudden! Tell me the reasons, please - I don't understand that !** To give the whole thing a positive turn - **I have got many excellent answers (reactions :) ) up to now and it would be a pity to stop the thing for whatever reasons.**

Comment: This post on the main Meta for Stack Exchange has a detailed explanation of why, and what you can do about it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/273494

Comment: You could have said you were prevented from posting questions since the beginning! It seemed you were referring to the less enthusiastic response from users, and the odd closure. So, now you know. Ignoring comments, can cost you dearly. Although, I have to say, banning you rom posting new questions seems overly harsh. But that's AI for you, they don't have intelligence, they only see zero votes and downvotes and then the system takes over. No one can help, only if you get a few upvotes might the ban get unblocked. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Meanwhile I have studied ColleenV's last post and link and there is mentioned **I must not delete questions; but I deleted questions**, I deleted those questions that didn't get an answer - sometimes because the phrases were dated or obsolete. **I thought this should relieve the forum community of a burden** because some users criticized that. **I now suspect this is the reason of the ban - maybe of an automatic ban.**

Comment: May I ask how many questions you deleted?

Comment: I got my answer from Laurel.

Comment: Yes, that' correct: I deleted 21 questions, the last one (      Meaning of "They must have adjusted to London, more or less" [closed], source Alice Munro, *Deep-Holes*) was closed. Thank you for helping, once again.

Comment: This Q has a positive score: [I don't take much stock in mercantile Jack](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343527/) why would you delete that? This Q has one downvote and one upvote [Meaning of . . . "fill up on a clean break"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343032/) A perfectly fine question.

Comment: "I don't take much stock in mercantile Jack":                                                                                                                  You are perfectly right - but this question didn't get an answer as well, and FumbleFingers said in her/his comment "More outdated expressions to watch out for."

Comment: Those questions didn't get an answer because users were getting bored by then, and you were not listening to them. You carried on posting 46 questions. I now find there were even more questions because you had deleted some before I started my little investigation. Imaging someone posting 50 questions about Harry Potter and  the Philosopher's Stone in three months! Hang on... I think someone did just that but many years ago...

Comment: "Meaning of . . . "fill up on a clean break" - the same with this Q: gotube said: "I have enjoyed a lot of these questions and answering some of them, but I'm starting to wonder what they have to do with learning English? Almost none of the expressions you've asked about are current or common, so I don't see how you're learning anything about English. It seems you're using this site to help you understand a book you're reading, and that's it.                                                         "

Comment: *Only* 30 questions about [Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22philosopher%27s%20stone%22&searchOn=3) but by different users, and the book is, of course, contemporary. P.S I have over 10K and have "earned" the privilege to read deleted posted. So... have you only read the comments recently, or did you choose to ignore the light criticisms?

Comment: But an amazing [819 questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22Harry%20Potter%22&searchOn=3) about Harry Potter!

Comment: @ Mary-LouA- What's wrong here? What have I to do with "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone"?

Comment: I was hoping that you would see why someone who posted 50 questions about the same novel would be tiring and then I remembered that there used to be a user who posted an awful lot of questions about the series of novels by JK Rowling. I'm just saying you're not the first to ask questions about a particular book or a series of novels by the same author. Your error was not to add a little of research to show you had tried to find the answer online, and maybe these questions were better suited to EL&U. Uncommon obsolete language is not very helpful to learners unless they are advanced learners.

Comment: I very much apologize. It was a misunderstanding and it was late in the night. - *. .you would see why someone who posted 50 questions about the same novel would be tiring . . . I remembered that there used to be a user who posted an awful lot of questions about the series of novels by JK Rowling. I'm just saying you're not the first to ask questions about a particular book or a series of novels by the same author.*: As far as I remember there wasn't anybody complaining about the multitude of questions about one and the same novel actually. So, I couldn't say someone was tired of my questions.

Comment: @ Mari-Lou A - *Your error was not to add a little of research to show you had tried to find the answer online, and maybe these questions were better suited to EL&U. Uncommon obsolete language is not very helpful to learners unless they are advanced learners.*: Some users complained about a little research, though, and most of those that were annoyed complained about the dated or obsolete phrases. - Do you think I should post questions about The Wrecker on EL&U in the future? https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5964/is-historical-english-interpretation-part-of-ells-remit

Comment: @philphil - maybe people were being 'polite'. I know I was growing tired of seeing your name under yet another question about that RLS book.

Comment: Posting yet [another question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346969/stand-forth-to-himself-literal-and-figurative-meaning) about an archaic or obsolete turn of phrase in RLS's novel means you either haven't got a clue why users downvoted your contributions or you don't care, also see M.Harvey's comment above.  I'm done.

Comment: I don't understand you. Didn't you read this                                                             https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5964/is-historical-english-interpretation-part-of-ells-remit? Think it over once again, please :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system looks at all of your contributions and will block you from asking questions if you have too many downvoted, closed, or deleted questions (the exact algorithm is a secret that's not even known by moderators). Your last question, when it got downvoted once, was merely [the last straw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_that_broke_the_camel%27s_back). Then you deleted a bunch of the questions you asked, which likely has [dug you into the hole](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/dig-into-a-hole) further.

Maybe some of this negative reception is that people don't like the redundancy of the questions, but there's little you can do about that now. However, one problem you can fix is that you don't include any research you've done in most of your questions. No, including it in the comments after the fact isn't enough. And, like I said, self-deleting questions is only hurting you.

My suggestion would be to improve your closed questions first, in the hopes of getting them open again. (Note: you'll probably need help undeleting any that were deleted by Community automatically, so I would start with the ones that aren't deleted or are self-deleted.) The questions you self-deleted that aren't closed would also be good to fix up (to hopefully avoid further downvotes) and undelete.

### Helpful links

[All deleted questions for the current user](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current)

Recently self-deleted questions for philphil:

- [must have vs. would have to have](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/341931/must-have-vs-would-have-to-have)
- [What does "the strain I've given the credit" mean in this context?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/342115/what-does-the-strain-ive-given-the-credit-mean-in-this-context)
- [What meaning does "should have" express in this context?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/342128/what-meaning-does-should-have-express-in-this-context)
- [Meaning of "...he answered like a little man"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/342177/meaning-of-he-answered-like-a-little-man)
- [Meaning of . . . , "I'm laying a little dark"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/342217/meaning-of-im-laying-a-little-dark)
- [Meaning of . . . "fill up on a clean break"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343032/meaning-of-fill-up-on-a-clean-break)
- [I don't take much stock in mercantile Jack](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343527/i-dont-take-much-stock-in-mercantile-jack)
- [. . . as sound a line as can be produced upon this coast](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343641/as-sound-a-line-as-can-be-produced-upon-this-coast)
- [I can't see but what you've got to support and bed and board with him to the end of time](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343837/i-cant-see-but-what-youve-got-to-support-and-bed-and-board-with-him-to-the-end)
- [Meaning of "They must have adjusted to London, more or less" [closed]](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/345294/meaning-of-they-must-have-adjusted-to-london-more-or-less)

There are 21 deleted questions in total. Some of them were locked here on ELL because they were deleted after being migrated from ELU, but I unlocked them.

Comment: Was the OP question banned over five days ago or *after* they deleted the questions?

Comment: @Mari-LouA They were question banned when they asked this meta question, at which point their [most recent main site question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/345294/41273) was not deleted and scored -1. They were deleting questions before that point and they deleted questions after that, but it probably wouldn't be useful to make a timeline. I can't say how much work OP needs to put in because I have no idea how deep they are into the question ban, just that they're still banned.

Comment: The questions are on topic even though they all seem alike, and the OP could have shown some "research" but they are perfectly valid questions. Some are interesting from a lexical point of view, if you love words and archaic words they are a trove. The OP should edit and add a dictionary definition where possible, then they can ask if a phrase is/was derogatory, only used in the UK, what would be their modern-day equivalents, whether these expressions are used today etc. Personally, I'm quite curious about Q4 and Q6

Comment: @Mari-LouA While I didn't review any of OP's closed questions in depth, I'd like to change ELL's "research" close reason in the same way I'm [redoing ELU's](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15694/191178). There are a lot of questions in the close queue that shouldn't be there, and some questions are definitely getting closed when they really can't be answered by a dictionary. (I just need to wrap up ELU's change first for my own sanity.) But either way, OP needs for people to upvote them, not downvote, and including research is the way to go for that I think.

Comment: I think the automatic system needs to change. Question banning should be based on content and whether a Q is off-topic or not. Many (the majority?) of the deleted posts were deleted by the OP themself. One question got 2 downvotes the others were stuck at zero or did not have a positive score because they had received one upvote and one downvote. That's not worthy of being question banned. Are question bans handled exactly the same way across the network? Should a question's merit on ELL be based on Stack Overflow's numbers?

Comment: @Mari-LouA It does work the same across the network, with only meta sites being different, but there's not much point in discussing it here since it would need to be changed by the developers (which is extremely unlikely to happen). That's why I want to focus on what I can change or otherwise influence, like the stuff I mentioned. If you feel certain types of questions are getting closed or downvoted unfairly, you could ask a new meta question here too.

Answer (score 5):

While tracing back the list of questions asked by the OP on the main site, a few comments caught my eye:

November 29, 2023

> - [I think this RLS book is getting a bit wearisome. I don't want to answer in case this question is booted](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/344724/whats-meant-by-he-went-the-pace-extraordinary-go-the-pace#comment666199_344724): P.1.b. 1829– colloquial. to go the pace: to move at great speed in the course of a hunt, race, etc.; (hence) to proceed in a vigorous, energetic, or dissipated way. For some reason, it appeared: *link to Oxford English Dictionary's definition for [*pace*](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/pace_n1?tl=true)*

"For some reason, it appeared" means the commenter did not expect to find the definition for *pace* in the OED.

> - @philphil I suspected that before long you *would* be using outdated expressions such as [methinks](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=methinks&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). [I suggest you put RLS to one side](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/344724/whats-meant-by-he-went-the-pace-extraordinary-go-the-pace#comment666200_344724), as you are plainly struggling with it anyway, and read something more contemporary.

November 23, 2023 (EL&U)

> - I don't think that level of detailed logical analysis is relevant. [The cited usage is a hopelessly outdated idiom](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/615041/meaning-of-bellairs-had-the-address-and-i-was-the-more-deceived-or-carthew-wou#comment1563302_615041), and Kate's suggested ***unless I was much mistaken*** is exactly what we say today in such contexts.

November 17, 2023

> - Several times now, I have cited links to 19th century dictionaries available online and downloadable as PDFs. [Why do you continue to consult contemporary dictionaries on these questions relating to *The Wrecker*?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/344105/meaning-of-make-out-in-you-didnt-somehow-make-out-to-give-us-the-th#comment664179_344105) Dictionaries with a contemporary focus are often not going to tell you about things that have fallen out of use

October 11, 2023

> - Soon enough we can read *The Wrecker* [in its entirety](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/342546/what-is-the-meaning-of-lying-over-under-all-plain-sail#comment658894_342546) on ELL :)

October 7, 2023

> - ...[do you really stop to look up every unknown usage while reading this text?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/342416/meaning-of-to-think-of-those-old-tin-type-times-about-turned-my-head#comment658317_342416) Even lots of native Anglophones might struggle with *like some blame' fairy story, in clover, a visit of God-speed*, etc. You must have this book in one hand, and a dictionary in the other!

It appears that your first question about the novel is dated September 24, 2023

[What do you take "buy over our head" to mean in the following context?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/341893/what-do-you-take-buy-over-our-head-to-mean-in-the-following-context)

Excluding any questions that may have been deleted, the OP has [posted a total of 46 questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A177850%20is%3Aquestion%20%22the%20Wrecker%22) about the novel “The Wrecker” on ELL. And another [12 questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3A488036%20%22The%20Wrecker%22&searchOn=3) on EL&U

### The OP asked “What's wrong with my questions all of a sudden?"

The problem is people have attempted to tell the OP that they are getting weary (bored) with the same type of questions. The presentation is nearly always the same, the source is *definitely* the same, and the type of answers posted are pretty much the same. They have repeatedly reminded the OP that the expressions, phrases and words from the novel are either uncommon, [dated](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/342005/what-do-you-take-can-have-nothing-to-say-to-something-to-mean-in-this-co#comment657024_342005) or [obsolete](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/342004/what-does-be-blown-upon-mean-there#comment657008_342004). For example,

> Is the phrase "[I am agreeably disappointed in your behaviour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/345214/usage-of-i-am-agreeably-disappointed-in)" common nowadays or is it obsolete - is it an understatement or is it a quirky jest?@philphil

December 11, 2023

> - I don't suppose it was ever common. It's an oxymoron.
> - [*Nothing* in this book is "common nowadays!](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/345214/usage-of-i-am-agreeably-disappointed-in#comment668055_345214)

In a comment below the meta post, I mused:

> I think the real problem lies with the general decline of interesting questions, if the site had ten good questions a day users would be more engaged

By this I mean seeing the same novel crop up every couple of days will create a sense of frustration especially among those users who have hinted that sense of frustration. It's as if you are stubbornly ignoring their observations.

You're absolutely free to ignore users who have commented on your posts. Moreover, you are reading a challenging text, kudos to you, but you must have an *inkling* as to why your posts are not being received so positively as before?

---

RLS = Robert Louis Stevenson

Comment: A very insightful answer.

Comment: That might apply to OP's other questions, but this one is from a more contemporary source.

Comment: @gotube "What's wrong with my **questions**...?" The OP is talking in the plural, the newest question on ELL is not the problem. It follows the same structure, the same formula, it is asking about a phrase and its meaning.

Comment: And this is why being kind and answering questions that should probably be closed for lacking detail is a problem. The person asking learns that "this pattern works" and starts using it and then is confused when all the sudden people get annoyed by it.

Answer (score 3):

The [Help Center page "Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?" that the warning links to](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) has a good explanation. I'm curious why that didn't help you understand the problem.

There's a very detailed explanation at [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/273494) I've excerpted a few key points below.

> An automatic filter is in place to ban questions or answers from IP addresses or accounts with a history of extremely poor posts.
>
> To avoid bypassing the filter, its internal rules are a secret, but it is partly based on downvotes cast by other members of the communities. If other members of the site consistently give your posts a low ranking, you should try to identify the reason(s) for this.
>
> To help prevent you from encountering a ban, the system will give you a warning if you are on the road to a ban, and may temporarily prevent you from posting questions or answers for a few days. If, despite these warnings and rate limits, you continue to post too many poorly-received questions or answers, you will be altogether banned from posting more, and you will see the error message.
>
> If a post was poorly received (downvoted or closed), those negative marks will continue to count against your account even if the post is deleted! Whenever possible, try to fix posts instead of deleting them.
>
> Automatic bans never expire or "time out". This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action, you will never be allowed to freely post again. The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways.
>
> Moderators cannot lift the ban.
>
> Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts!

If you've deleted some poorly received posts, you may want to undelete them and try to fix them up. If you're unsure how to fix a question, or if you've fixed a question and you would like community members to take another look at it, you can post about it here on ELL's meta.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that users with 10K can see deleted posts but the OP has to first give a link. I have the feeling any deleted posts are countable on one hand. I don't think the questions were actually "bad", they had context and they were on topic, I think users' biggest complaint was their repetition. How come a moderator doesn't know if a user has been question banned? Shouldn't there be some sort of notice on a person's account? No?

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, it's an automated system and mods have no ability to affect it, so they don't get notified. I don't remember if there is a mod-only notation on the account. The user should get a warning that would hopefully prompt them to ask why they're getting that warning before they're actually question banned. Maybe the wording or timing of that warning is not well designed though. Users being confused about why they're question-banned seems to come up a lot.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I just realize the warning has a link to more information; I wonder if the problem is that SE tries to solve everything with a wall of text instead of something simpler that would be easier for learners to understand. It might be worthwhile to add a section to [the contributor's guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4783/9161)

Comment: I know the ban is automatic, and mods have nothing to do with banning an individual. I'm asking why they are unable to tell if a user has been banned. Why must moderators, even ordinary users for that matter,  wait until the user actually spells it out?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Because the company thinks that the walls of text and links to more walls of text solve the problem, so human intervention is not necessary. SE is confused about what their focus should be... They think their purpose is  ferrying information between askers and answerers, when they're real purpose should be connecting people so they can collaborate on creating a reference library of knowledge and helping people find what they need in it. (and I don't remember whether mods can see if someone is question banned or not - it's probably buried somewhere)

Comment: (ugh, and I just saw that auto-correct made me look stupid by substituting they're for their and it's too late to fix it. That is a feature where I would welcome better AI, or at least AI that doesn't seem to hate me.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Moderators can tell if someone is question or answer banned by checking their profile, though I can't say that I check it unless I have a reason to think it's relevant or I'm looking at other information in that area.

Comment: @Laurel so there *is* something. And I'm sorry, but there was a very good reason to look at the OP's profile, at the very least checking the number of posts submitted about "The Wrecker". Obviously I'm not blaming gotube, he was the only mod who showed some interest. Where is Glofindel in all this? He's the one with the wealth of experience, how many sites is he a moderator on? Six? Seven? No, it's NINE.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think Glorfindel is dealing with personal stuff right now. I don't have any details other than he's not been very active lately. As for me, I started an answer to this meta question but never finished writing it—I'll just say that I'm a mess.

Comment: @Laurel  Re Glorfindel, family and work will, and should–rightly so–take priority, and if being a moderator takes away valuable time away, then they should step down. Let someone with more free time and greater enthusiasm take over. I also think moderators should be made to retire after six years.

Comment: 'To avoid bypassing the filter, its internal rules are a secret, but it is partly based on downvotes cast by other members of the communities. ' - so casting down and close votes is an important part of curating the site.